# Time adjustment with ajax and mysql

Tags: mysql, ajax

I am developing a facebookapp where two users play against and the time counts to zero. Whats the best way to do this? I tried to send an ajax request to a php script every second which updates the database with the current time in seconds that the user has left. But sometimes I have 0 values at the columns and the user has no time left. The query strings are ok. Would it be better to store timestamps?

If I would not store the times and the user refresh the page he gets the time back.

Comment: Good questions show the code, so that answers can be targeted at the specific cause of a problem. Identify a subset of your application that demonstrates the problem, and post it.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you save the exact timestamp when the clock shows zero?

You can handle all outputs with these one number. You don't have to send requests all the time. Only at first and than when your timestamp reached.

Comment: Not really, i have to update the time when a user make a move, so that the opponent knows his rest time. And if the lag is to big i need an adjustment.

Comment: Have you thought about Websocket? (SecureWebsocket)
Than you have live data